# Where is my tablet's memory card mounted on laptop?

Tags: ubuntu, android, automounting, gvfs

I connected my Asus fonepad7 tablet to my laptop via usb. My laptop automatically detects it & opens. But I'm unable to find where the memory card of my tablet mounted on laptop. Just see below, when I put cursor on the tablet device, it shows "mtp://[usb:002,003]/"
[image: Mount point]

As I'm unable to find the mount point, I can't use command line for accessing the tablet. Also, commands "mount" & "df" doesn't reflect anything regarding the tablet.

I'm working on Ubuntu 13.04

> **EDIT#1**

This edit is with ref. to the answer posted by edvinas.me

I got the mount point as "/run/user/ravbholua/gvfs".
But the issue is that all the files & folders are named as numerals. Please see below:

```
ravbholua@ravbholua-Aspire-5315:/run/user/ravbholua/gvfs/mtp:host=%5Busb%3A002%2C008%5D$ ls
65537
ravbholua@ravbholua-Aspire-5315:/run/user/ravbholua/gvfs/mtp:host=%5Busb%3A002%2C008%5D$ cd *
ravbholua@ravbholua-Aspire-5315:/run/user/ravbholua/gvfs/mtp:host=%5Busb%3A002%2C008%5D/65537$ ls
1   100  105   11  1301  1420  1533  1597  2    223  226  3   4    422  426  5  85  9
10  104  1072  12  1310  1496  1547  1806  212  224  232  30  421  424  430  6  86  900
ravbholua@ravbholua-Aspire-5315:/run/user/ravbholua/gvfs/mtp:host=%5Busb%3A002%2C008%5D/65537$ cp 30 ~
cp: cannot open ‘30’ for reading: Operation not supported
```

The name of the files & folders as shown in GUI is by names but here it is numerals.
Also I'm unable to copy any file. Please look at the above code.

Answer (score 0):

Your tablet is mounted via `gvfs` instead of usual tools. You should check `~/.gvfs` or `/run/user/<login>/gvfs` directories.

Comment: Great! It has worked but some issues are there as mentioned in the edit of my Q.

Comment: Though I've got the mount point, I'm unable to proceed ahead at all as is clear from my edited Q.

Comment: Why not use some file manager which supports gvfs? Your terminal commands `cp`, `mv` etc CANNOT talk to GVFS.

Comment: for example, try `gmtp`