# How to back-up files from nautilus retaining the time stamp?

Tags: backup, file-copy, nautilus, mtp

I connected my android tablet (Asus fonepad7 me372cg) to laptop using usb cable. It showed up in nautilus in Ubuntu 13.04. I've to back-up the files in the tablet (specially the videos & photos) to my laptop. The issue I find here is that via nautilus when I copy-paste, the original time stamp gets lost & the current time gets linked with the copied files. This I don't want. Is there a way to achieve this via nautilus which will retain the time stamp?

I know that via command line, I can achieve that using `tar` or `cpio`. But the reason I'm not using cli is that the file names in the terminal for the tablet aren't displayed rightly. (I've a thread regarding this issue [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/125359/where-is-my-tablets-memory-card-mounted-on-laptop)) Rather than the names of the files & folders, it's reflecting as numbers. I've come across this issue in google search engine which I will try to resolve later. But till then I need a solution to achieve it via nautilus!

By nautilus, I mean the GUI as shown below:
[image: nautilus]

Comment: (IF you don't find nautilus solution)It looks like someone tried doing something similar, this command may work `<commands> | cpio -p --reset-access-time --preserve-modification-time /path/to/dest/dir`, but for further explanation I would check out the discussion. http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/red-hat-31/how-to-preserve-all-timestamps-while-copying-files-742757/
 (also I believe this is RHEL)

Comment: Is your phone connecting as USB mass storage, or via MTP?

Comment: @NoTime I don't want CLI commands (via terminal) as the file names of the tablet files aren't displayed properly in CLI. I'm looking for GUI (or nautilus) based method.

Comment: @derobert when I connected my tablet with laptop using usb cable, it messaged in the tablet `connected as media device`.

Comment: This shows how to do it through to a NAS. I am not sure you would do connect to server when mounting your android however. It looks like it may.
http://askubuntu.com/questions/226033/how-can-i-preserve-file-modification-times-when-copying-to-a-nas

Comment: My *guess* would be that when connecting over MTP you can't... Of course, you could always put your files inside a tar file, then tar would preserve the times.

Comment: @derobert can it the done without cli but via GUI (or nautilus)?

Comment: @Ravi select some files in Nautilus, right click, select 'compress'. It will default to tar & compress, but you can select just tar.

Comment: @derobert it isn't working for android storage. I'm getting error: "operation not supported by backend". I can do the same (i.e. compress & tar ) for the laptop files but not android.