# unable to back-up data from android tablet to laptop using tar!

Tags: backup, tar, android

I'm using `tar` to back-up data from my android tablet to laptop. But it is showing some error.

```
ravbholua@ravbholua-Aspire-5315:/run/user/ravbholua/gvfs/mtp:host=%5Busb%3A002%2C003%5D/65537/9$ tar -cvf /media/ravbholua/f34890dd-20d2-4d78-92c9-1de7c0957f00/jackal.tar .
./
tar: ./33: Cannot open: Operation not supported
tar: ./34: Cannot open: Operation not supported
tar: ./35: Cannot open: Operation not supported
tar: ./36: Cannot open: Operation not supported
tar: ./37: Cannot open: Operation not supported
tar: ./38: Cannot open: Operation not supported
./50/
./50/62/
tar: ./50/209: Cannot open: Operation not supported
tar: ./50/210: Cannot open: Operation not supported
tar: ./50/211: Cannot open: Operation not supported
tar: ./50/216: Cannot open: Operation not supported
tar: ./50/217: Cannot open: Operation not supported
tar: ./50/218: Cannot open: Operation not supported
./50/236/
./50/249/
tar: ./50/903: Cannot open: Operation not supported
tar: ./50/904: Cannot open: Operation not supported
tar: ./50/905: Cannot open: Operation not supported
tar: ./50/906: Cannot open: Operation not supported
tar: ./50/907: Cannot open: Operation not supported

ravbholua@ravbholua-Aspire-5315:/run/user/ravbholua/gvfs/mtp:host=%5Busb%3A002%2C003%5D/65537/9$ sudo tar -cvf /media/ravbholua/f34890dd-20d2-4d78-92c9-1de7c0957f00/jackal.tar .
[sudo] password for ravbholua: 
tar: .: Cannot stat: Permission denied
tar: Exiting with failure status due to previous errors
```

(I'm unable to take back-up from nautilus even as clear from [this thread](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/131693/how-to-back-up-files-from-nautilus-retaining-the-time-stamp?noredirect=1#comment210957_131693))

(I would like to add that the file names aren't displayed clearly in my laptop for the android files in the terminal. I've [this thread](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/131693/how-to-back-up-files-from-nautilus-retaining-the-time-stamp?noredirect=1#comment210957_131693)  regarding this.)

#### EDIT

I used `rsync` command but the same error.

```
ravbholua@ravbholua-Aspire-5315:/run/user/ravbholua/gvfs/mtp:host=%5Busb%3A002%2C003%5D/65537/50$ rsync -avz ./ ~/Dow*
sending incremental file list
./
rsync: send_files failed to open "/run/user/ravbholua/gvfs/mtp:host=%5Busb%3A002%2C003%5D/65537/50/1078": Operation not supported (95)
rsync: send_files failed to open "/run/user/ravbholua/gvfs/mtp:host=%5Busb%3A002%2C003%5D/65537/50/1079": Operation not supported (95)
rsync: send_files failed to open "/run/user/ravbholua/gvfs/mtp:host=%5Busb%3A002%2C003%5D/65537/50/1080": Operation not supported (95)
rsync: send_files failed to open "/run/user/ravbholua/gvfs/mtp:host=%5Busb%3A002%2C003%5D/65537/50/1081": Operation not supported (95)
rsync: send_files failed to open "/run/user/ravbholua/gvfs/mtp:host=%5Busb%3A002%2C003%5D/65537/50/1082": Operation not supported (95)
rsync: send_files failed to open "/run/user/ravbholua/gvfs/mtp:host=%5Busb%3A002%2C003%5D/65537/50/1083": Operation not supported (95)
rsync: send_files failed to open "/run/user/ravbholua/gvfs/mtp:host=%5Busb%3A002%2C003%5D/65537/50/1085": Operation not supported (95)
rsync: send_files failed to open "/run/user/ravbholua/gvfs/mtp:host=%5Busb%3A002%2C003%5D/65537/50/1086": Operation not supported (95)
rsync: send_files failed to open "/run/user/ravbholua/gvfs/mtp:host=%5Busb%3A002%2C003%5D/65537/50/1087": Operation not supported (95)
rsync: send_files failed to open "/run/user/ravbholua/gvfs/mtp:host=%5Busb%3A002%2C003%5D/65537/50/1088": Operation not supported (95)
rsync: send_files failed to open "/run/user/ravbholua/gvfs/mtp:host=%5Busb%3A002%2C003%5D/65537/50/1089": Operation not supported (95)
rsync: send_files failed to open "/run/user/ravbholua/gvfs/mtp:host=%5Busb%3A002%2C003%5D/65537/50/1090": Operation not supported (95)
rsync: send_files failed to open "/run/user/ravbholua/gvfs/mtp:host=%5Busb%3A002%2C003%5D/65537/50/1091": Operation not supported (95)
rsync: send_files failed to open "/run/user/ravbholua/gvfs/mtp:host=%5Busb%3A002%2C003%5D/65537/50/1094": Operation not supported (95)
rsync: send_files failed to open "/run/user/ravbholua/gvfs/mtp:host=%5Busb%3A002%2C003%5D/65537/50/1103": Operation not supported (95)
rsync: send_files failed to open "/run/user/ravbholua/gvfs/mtp:host=%5Busb%3A002%2C003%5D/65537/50/1154": Operation not supported (95)
rsync: send_files failed to open "/run/user/ravbholua/gvfs/mtp:host=%5Busb%3A002%2C003%5D/65537/50/1155": Operation not supported (95)
rsync: send_files failed to open "/run/user/ravbholua/gvfs/mtp:host=%5Busb%3A002%2C003%5D/65537/50/1156": Operation not supported (95)
rsync: send_files failed to open "/run/user/ravbholua/gvfs/mtp:host=%5Busb%3A002%2C003%5D/65537/50/1157": Operation not supported (95)
rsync: send_files failed to open "/run/user/ravbholua/gvfs/mtp:host=%5Busb%3A002%2C003%5D/65537/50/1158": Operation not supported (95)
rsync: send_files failed to open "/run/user/ravbholua/gvfs/mtp:host=%5Busb%3A002%2C003%5D/65537/50/1159": Operation not supported (95)
rsync: send_files failed to open "/run/user/ravbholua/gvfs/mtp:host=%5Busb%3A002%2C003%5D/65537/50/1160": Operation not supported (95)
rsync: send_files failed to open "/run/user/ravbholua/gvfs/mtp:host=%5Busb%3A002%2C003%5D/65537/50/1161": Operation not supported (95)
rsync: send_files failed to open "/run/user/ravbholua/gvfs/mtp:host=%5Busb%3A002%2C003%5D/65537/50/1162": Operation not supported (95)
rsync: send_files failed to open "/run/user/ravbholua/gvfs/mtp:host=%5Busb%3A002%2C003%5D/65537/50/1171": Operation not supported (95)
rsync: send_files failed to open "/run/user/ravbholua/gvfs/mtp:host=%5Busb%3A002%2C003%5D/65537/50/1172": Operation not supported (95)
rsync: send_files failed to open "/run/user/ravbholua/gvfs/mtp:host=%5Busb%3A002%2C003%5D/65537/50/1278": Operation not supported (95)
rsync: send_files failed to open "/run/user/ravbholua/gvfs/mtp:host=%5Busb%3A002%2C003%5D/65537/50/1279": Operation not supported (95)
rsync: send_files failed to open "/run/user/ravbholua/gvfs/mtp:host=%5Busb%3A002%2C003%5D/65537/50/1280": Operation not supported (95)
rsync: send_files failed to open "/run/user/ravbholua/gvfs/mtp:host=%5Busb%3A002%2C003%5D/65537/50/1282": Operation not supported (95)
rsync: send_files failed to open "/run/user/ravbholua/gvfs/mtp:host=%5Busb%3A002%2C003%5D/65537/50/1283": Operation not supported (95)
rsync: send_files failed to open "/run/user/ravbholua/gvfs/mtp:host=%5Busb%3A002%2C003%5D/65537/50/1284": Operation not supported (95)
rsync: send_files failed to open "/run/user/ravbholua/gvfs/mtp:host=%5Busb%3A002%2C003%5D/65537/50/1285": Operation not supported (95)
rsync: send_files failed to open "/run/user/ravbholua/gvfs/mtp:host=%5Busb%3A002%2C003%5D/65537/50/1286": Operation not supported (95)
rsync: send_files failed to open "/run/user/ravbholua/gvfs/mtp:host=%5Busb%3A002%2C003%5D/65537/50/1287": Operation not supported (95)
rsync: send_files failed to open "/run/user/ravbholua/gvfs/mtp:host=%5Busb%3A002%2C003%5D/65537/50/1397": Operation not supported (95)
rsync: send_files failed to open "/run/user/ravbholua/gvfs/mtp:host=%5Busb%3A002%2C003%5D/65537/50/1398": Operation not supported (95)
rsync: send_files failed to open "/run/user/ravbholua/gvfs/mtp:host=%5Busb%3A002%2C003%5D/65537/50/1399": Operation not supported (95)
rsync: send_files failed to open "/run/user/ravbholua/gvfs/mtp:host=%5Busb%3A002%2C003%5D/65537/50/1400": Operation not supported (95)
rsync: send_files failed to open "/run/user/ravbholua/gvfs/mtp:host=%5Busb%3A002%2C003%5D/65537/50/1401": Operation not supported (95)
rsync: send_files failed to open "/run/user/ravbholua/gvfs/mtp:host=%5Busb%3A002%2C003%5D/65537/50/1402": Operation not supported (95)
rsync: send_files failed to open "/run/user/ravbholua/gvfs/mtp:host=%5Busb%3A002%2C003%5D/65537/50/1403": Operation not supported (95)
rsync: send_files failed to open "/run/user/ravbholua/gvfs/mtp:host=%5Busb%3A002%2C003%5D/65537/50/1404": Operation not supported (95)
rsync: send_files failed to open "/run/user/ravbholua/gvfs/mtp:host=%5Busb%3A002%2C003%5D/65537/50/1405": Operation not supported (95)
rsync: send_files failed to open "/run/user/ravbholua/gvfs/mtp:host=%5Busb%3A002%2C003%5D/65537/50/1406": Operation not supported (95)
rsync: send_files failed to open "/run/user/ravbholua/gvfs/mtp:host=%5Busb%3A002%2C003%5D/65537/50/1407": Operation not supported (95)
rsync: send_files failed to open "/run/user/ravbholua/gvfs/mtp:host=%5Busb%3A002%2C003%5D/65537/50/1408": Operation not supported (95)
rsync: send_files failed to open "/run/user/ravbholua/gvfs/mtp:host=%5Busb%3A002%2C003%5D/65537/50/1409": Operation not supported (95)
rsync: send_files failed to open "/run/user/ravbholua/gvfs/mtp:host=%5Busb%3A002%2C003%5D/65537/50/1501": Operation not supported (95)
rsync: send_files failed to open "/run/user/ravbholua/gvfs/mtp:host=%5Busb%3A002%2C003%5D/65537/50/1512": Operation not supported (95)
rsync: send_files failed to open "/run/user/ravbholua/gvfs/mtp:host=%5Busb%3A002%2C003%5D/65537/50/1635": Operation not supported (95)
rsync: send_files failed to open "/run/user/ravbholua/gvfs/mtp:host=%5Busb%3A002%2C003%5D/65537/50/1645": Operation not supported (95)
rsync: send_files failed to open "/run/user/ravbholua/gvfs/mtp:host=%5Busb%3A002%2C003%5D/65537/50/1646": Operation not supported (95)
rsync: send_files failed to open "/run/user/ravbholua/gvfs/mtp:host=%5Busb%3A002%2C003%5D/65537/50/1647": Operation not supported (95)
rsync: send_files failed to open "/run/user/ravbholua/gvfs/mtp:host=%5Busb%3A002%2C003%5D/65537/50/1650": Operation not supported (95)
rsync: send_files failed to open "/run/user/ravbholua/gvfs/mtp:host=%5Busb%3A002%2C003%5D/65537/50/1655": Operation not supported (95)
rsync: send_files failed to open "/run/user/ravbholua/gvfs/mtp:host=%5Busb%3A002%2C003%5D/65537/50/1656": Operation not supported (95)
rsync: send_files failed to open "/run/user/ravbholua/gvfs/mtp:host=%5Busb%3A002%2C003%5D/65537/50/1657": Operation not supported (95)
rsync: send_files failed to open "/run/user/ravbholua/gvfs/mtp:host=%5Busb%3A002%2C003%5D/65537/50/1660": Operation not supported (95)
rsync: send_files failed to open "/run/user/ravbholua/gvfs/mtp:host=%5Busb%3A002%2C003%5D/65537/50/1661": Operation not supported (95)
rsync: send_files failed to open "/run/user/ravbholua/gvfs/mtp:host=%5Busb%3A002%2C003%5D/65537/50/1662": Operation not supported (95)
rsync: send_files failed to open "/run/user/ravbholua/gvfs/mtp:host=%5Busb%3A002%2C003%5D/65537/50/1663": Operation not supported (95)
rsync: send_files failed to open "/run/user/ravbholua/gvfs/mtp:host=%5Busb%3A002%2C003%5D/65537/50/1664": Operation not supported (95)
rsync: send_files failed to open "/run/user/ravbholua/gvfs/mtp:host=%5Busb%3A002%2C003%5D/65537/50/1665": Operation not supported (95)
rsync: send_files failed to open "/run/user/ravbholua/gvfs/mtp:host=%5Busb%3A002%2C003%5D/65537/50/1666": Operation not supported (95)
rsync: send_files failed to open "/run/user/ravbholua/gvfs/mtp:host=%5Busb%3A002%2C003%5D/65537/50/1667": Operation not supported (95)
rsync: send_files failed to open "/run/user/ravbholua/gvfs/mtp:host=%5Busb%3A002%2C003%5D/65537/50/1668": Operation not supported (95)
rsync: send_files failed to open "/run/user/ravbholua/gvfs/mtp:host=%5Busb%3A002%2C003%5D/65537/50/1669": Operation not supported (95)
rsync: send_files failed to open "/run/user/ravbholua/gvfs/mtp:host=%5Busb%3A002%2C003%5D/65537/50/1670": Operation not supported (95)
rsync: send_files failed to open "/run/user/ravbholua/gvfs/mtp:host=%5Busb%3A002%2C003%5D/65537/50/1671": Operation not supported (95)
rsync: send_files failed to open "/run/user/ravbholua/gvfs/mtp:host=%5Busb%3A002%2C003%5D/65537/50/1675": Operation not supported (95)
rsync: send_files failed to open "/run/user/ravbholua/gvfs/mtp:host=%5Busb%3A002%2C003%5D/65537/50/1676": Operation not supported (95)
rsync: send_files failed to open "/run/user/ravbholua/gvfs/mtp:host=%5Busb%3A002%2C003%5D/65537/50/209": Operation not supported (95)
rsync: send_files failed to open "/run/user/ravbholua/gvfs/mtp:host=%5Busb%3A002%2C003%5D/65537/50/210": Operation not supported (95)
rsync: send_files failed to open "/run/user/ravbholua/gvfs/mtp:host=%5Busb%3A002%2C003%5D/65537/50/211": Operation not supported (95)
rsync: send_files failed to open "/run/user/ravbholua/gvfs/mtp:host=%5Busb%3A002%2C003%5D/65537/50/216": Operation not supported (95)
rsync: send_files failed to open "/run/user/ravbholua/gvfs/mtp:host=%5Busb%3A002%2C003%5D/65537/50/217": Operation not supported (95)
rsync: send_files failed to open "/run/user/ravbholua/gvfs/mtp:host=%5Busb%3A002%2C003%5D/65537/50/218": Operation not supported (95)
rsync: send_files failed to open "/run/user/ravbholua/gvfs/mtp:host=%5Busb%3A002%2C003%5D/65537/50/2841": Operation not supported (95)
rsync: send_files failed to open "/run/user/ravbholua/gvfs/mtp:host=%5Busb%3A002%2C003%5D/65537/50/2842": Operation not supported (95)
rsync: send_files failed to open "/run/user/ravbholua/gvfs/mtp:host=%5Busb%3A002%2C003%5D/65537/50/2849": Operation not supported (95)
rsync: send_files failed to open "/run/user/ravbholua/gvfs/mtp:host=%5Busb%3A002%2C003%5D/65537/50/2850": Operation not supported (95)
rsync: send_files failed to open "/run/user/ravbholua/gvfs/mtp:host=%5Busb%3A002%2C003%5D/65537/50/2851": Operation not supported (95)
rsync: send_files failed to open "/run/user/ravbholua/gvfs/mtp:host=%5Busb%3A002%2C003%5D/65537/50/3118": Operation not supported (95)
rsync: send_files failed to open "/run/user/ravbholua/gvfs/mtp:host=%5Busb%3A002%2C003%5D/65537/50/903": Operation not supported (95)
rsync: send_files failed to open "/run/user/ravbholua/gvfs/mtp:host=%5Busb%3A002%2C003%5D/65537/50/904": Operation not supported (95)
rsync: send_files failed to open "/run/user/ravbholua/gvfs/mtp:host=%5Busb%3A002%2C003%5D/65537/50/905": Operation not supported (95)
rsync: send_files failed to open "/run/user/ravbholua/gvfs/mtp:host=%5Busb%3A002%2C003%5D/65537/50/906": Operation not supported (95)
rsync: send_files failed to open "/run/user/ravbholua/gvfs/mtp:host=%5Busb%3A002%2C003%5D/65537/50/907": Operation not supported (95)
rsync: send_files failed to open "/run/user/ravbholua/gvfs/mtp:host=%5Busb%3A002%2C003%5D/65537/50/910": Operation not supported (95)
1096/
rsync: send_files failed to open "/run/user/ravbholua/gvfs/mtp:host=%5Busb%3A002%2C003%5D/65537/50/1096/1102": Operation not supported (95)
1636/
rsync: send_files failed to open "/run/user/ravbholua/gvfs/mtp:host=%5Busb%3A002%2C003%5D/65537/50/1636/1637": Operation not supported (95)
rsync: send_files failed to open "/run/user/ravbholua/gvfs/mtp:host=%5Busb%3A002%2C003%5D/65537/50/1636/1638": Operation not supported (95)
rsync: send_files failed to open "/run/user/ravbholua/gvfs/mtp:host=%5Busb%3A002%2C003%5D/65537/50/1636/1639": Operation not supported (95)
rsync: send_files failed to open "/run/user/ravbholua/gvfs/mtp:host=%5Busb%3A002%2C003%5D/65537/50/1636/1640": Operation not supported (95)
rsync: send_files failed to open "/run/user/ravbholua/gvfs/mtp:host=%5Busb%3A002%2C003%5D/65537/50/1636/1641": Operation not supported (95)
rsync: send_files failed to open "/run/user/ravbholua/gvfs/mtp:host=%5Busb%3A002%2C003%5D/65537/50/1636/1642": Operation not supported (95)
rsync: send_files failed to open "/run/user/ravbholua/gvfs/mtp:host=%5Busb%3A002%2C003%5D/65537/50/1636/1643": Operation not supported (95)
rsync: send_files failed to open "/run/user/ravbholua/gvfs/mtp:host=%5Busb%3A002%2C003%5D/65537/50/1636/1644": Operation not supported (95)
236/
249/
62/

sent 2096 bytes  received 1916 bytes  2674.67 bytes/sec
total size is 2364535131  speedup is 589365.69
rsync error: some files/attrs were not transferred (see previous errors) (code 23) at main.c(1070) [sender=3.0.9]
```

Comment: What are these files? `file ./50/217` for example. This looks like these aren't actual files, they may be device files of some sort, but that's just a guess. If these are device files you could tell `tar` to exclude them via `tar --exclude ...`.

Comment: @slm  they're the actual files. Using sudo also didn't work.

Comment: Can you show the output of `file ./50/217`?

Comment: @slm Sorry for the delay. It is an image file (.jpg).

Comment: @slm I've to copy all my files (photos & videos especially) from tablet to laptop so that I can reset my tablet to company default as I'm facing issues with tablet. But I'm finding no way to do so that will retain the time stamp of the files which (time stamp is too important).

Comment: Can you `rsync -avz SRC DEST` the data from the media card?

Comment: @slm I will try that but just now I've come to know one new thing. When I connected my tablet to computer via usb cable, in the tablet it was mentioned "connected as media device. Touch to see other options". When I touched, it took me to a page heading "usb computer connection". There 2 options are there for connecting. Now it is connected as "Media device (MTP)". The other option is "camera(ptp)". This option says that it lets you transfer photos using camera software, & transfer any files on computers that don't support MTP. I will try this also.

Comment: Ahhh. Yeah there are 2 methods for accessing devices like this. Sounds like you'll want to use the MTP variety.

Comment: @slm please see my edited post. As I felt, it happened the same. The same error with rsync command also. The issue may be that the tablet is not mounted as usb storage device like pen-drive or external HDD. It is mounted via something like MTP.

Comment: Sorry, my suggestion of using `rsync` was before I knew you had the ability to mount it as MTP.

Comment: @slm yes my work is done when I chose the other option "camera(ptp)". After connecting using that option, shotwell software in my Ubuntu automatically opened & I was able to import the pics & videos to my laptop from tablet retaining the time stamp. Now I can reset my tablet to company default what I was telling earlier. Though I've to still look for the command line method for doing the same but there is no urgency for that. Just one clarification: I'd been earlier connecting as MTP which didn't serve my purpose, connecting via "camera(ptp)" has worked. I feel you are thinking otherwise.

Comment: I think I'm twisted around as well. I haven't had any devices with this issue for several years now. It was a Kodak digital camera that had this particular issue.

Comment: See here: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Digital_Cameras You could use this via command line: `gphoto2 --get-all-files`

Answer (score 3):

Yes, I've got the solution. See there were 2 options for connecting tablet.
1) Media device (MTP)
2) Camera (PTP)

I'd been using the 1st one where via command line I was failing to do & via GUI, I wasn't able to retain the time stamp. This option uses mtp to connect.
[image]

Then yesterday, it stroked my mind & I connected via the 2nd option , i.e. camera. Now via GUI (shotwell software), I was able to import the files.
Then in nautilus, I found it was connected not via mtp but gphoto2.
[image]

Now I was able to use the command line & copy via `cp -a` retaining the time stamp & it worked. Now I know all command line commands like `tar` will work as with any external HDD or pen-drive. A great relief!

Comment: @slm please look at the solution. I've got a way.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem and found a similar solution, except that I don't have a choice for using PTP over MTP on my device. What I did is : I installed gphotofs and ran

```
gphotofs ~/some-mount-point
```

then I could using rsync as before !